# "Moving kitchen sink." 3" vent is located at old location

Tags: plumbing

Moving the kitchen sink including the 3" waste line 6' downstream. 5' of 1 1/2" connects from the sink trap to the 3" waste line. The 3" vent is located at the old location. Will the function properly?

Comment: "*Will the function properly?*"  ???   Can you add  MORE details so we can grasp the situation better. It will help to get a more informed answer.

Comment: *i.e.* how is the pre-existing vent connected to the relocated waste line?